# Devtools пишет об ошибке. Отправка формы

Tags: javascript, form, null, submit

Пытаюсь обработать событие submit у формы.
Но еще до проверки получаю ошибку:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let buttonCall = document.querySelector('.callbtn');
        let formCall = document.querySelector('.uc-form-call');
        let closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
        let formField = document.querySelector('.form-field');
        let submitBtn = document.querySelector('.t-submit');
    
        buttonCall.addEventListener('click', function() {
            formCall.classList.add('form-on');
            document.body.classList.add('body-flow');
        });
    
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            formCall.classList.remove('form-on');
            document.body.classList.remove('body-flow');
        });
    
        formField.addEventListener('click', function() {
            formCall.classList.remove('form-on');
            document.body.classList.remove('body-flow');
        });
        
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            formCall.classList.remove('form-on');
            document.body.classList.remove('body-flow');
        });
    });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так делаю.

P.S. Работаю в конструкторе Tilda

Comment: Можете код формы приложить?

Comment: @rusgeli уф)) это будет весело) там в тильде такой беспредел по этому поводу) Код в комментарий вставить?

Comment: @rusgeli tilda очень коряво и не весь код позволяет выдернуть. Что именно необходимо из кода?

Comment: @rusgeli там около 2000 строк на одну форму......тильда.....

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что форма не найдена, перепроверьте айдишник формы, по которому вы ее ищете и сравните с тем, что указан в форме

Comment: @rusgeli проверял. ID верный. А что конкретно из кода формы необходимо прислать?

Comment: Смотрите: у вас ошибка гласит, что произошла попытка обращения к свойству/методу переменной, которая имеет значение NULL. Методы `querySelector` и `getElementById` возвращают NULL, если элементы не найдены. Значит одна из ваших переменных (кроме `formCall `) имеет значение NULL. Выведите их значения и посмотрите, какая имеет значение NULL

Comment: @rusgeli оуу. Странно. Я вывел в консоль все переменные и ни одна не вернула null. Форма в том числе. Отобразились все домузлы как надо. Но проверка (console.log('click');) на событие submit не сработала.

Comment: @rusgeli  я отредактировал код в вопросе

Comment: Значит либо ошибка не в этой части кода, либо я чего-то не вижу. DevTools точно на эту часть кода ругается? Приложите скрин ошибки и строчку кода, на которую он ссылается

Comment: @rusgeli теперь DevTools молчит. Никакой ошибки нет. Просто скрипт почему-то не срабатывает, хотя форма в переменной точно...я склонюсь на то, что это все таки cms и cms tilda. В ней особо с кодом не попляшешь. Видимо придется использовать ее функционал.

Comment: @rusgeli в итоге повесил обработчик на кнопку в форме. Все заработало.